# How to delete a pdf file if it does not contain text?

Tags: java, erase

I want to erase all pdf files that do not contain text. I tried to use a PdfBox.
Method `pdftoText` converts pdf to String.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException {


            String pdfText = PDFTextParser.pdftoText("xxx.pdf");                                        //files[i]);
            if (pdfText == "") {
                File toBeDeletedFile = new File(location+"xxx.pdf");
                if (toBeDeletedFile.delete()) {
                    System.out.println("success");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("still there");
                }
            }


        }


}
```

This did not bring any results

Answer (score 1):

`String` objects can not be compared using `==` in Java.

Please us the `String.equals()` method.

```
String s1 = "dat1";
String s2 = "dat2";

if(s1.equals(s2))
    //dostuff
else
    //dootherstuff
```